# Framework7: Adding a hidden value to picker

Tags: javascript, picker, html-framework-7

In a standard select list you can pass a hidden variable back to the form handler just by using the value attribute, i.e.:

```
<select>
    <option value="hidden-variable">Displayed Value</option>
</select>
```

However with Framework7's picker, it doesn't look like there's a way of achieving the same thing. It does allow you to specify 'value' and 'displayValue' for each column, but when you select a 'displayValue', it's the 'value' that gets shown in the actual field. i.e.:

```
var picker = myApp.picker({
    input: '#picker-input',
    cols: [
        {
            values: ['hidden-variable-1','hidden-variable-2'],
            displayValues: ['Displayed Value 1','Displayed Value 2']
        }
    ]
});
```

When you select 'Displayed Value 1' in the picker, it's 'hidden-variable-1' that shows in the field. Is there a way to write the hidden variable to a hidden input field and display the Display Value to the user?

Comment: Had a brainwave as a workaround - make the #picker-input field hidden and then add an onChange function to the picker which copies the displayValue into a visible field. I also added an onClick event to the visible field so the picker can be reopened when the field is clicked - but, it doesn't open and I can't figure out why. If I console.log out the picker object within the onClick function, the object exists but picker.Open() does nothing.

Comment: Ok, solved. This workaround method does work, I just needed to stopPropagation() before calling picker.Open()

Answer (score 1):

Not too late ?
Try to use the formatValue property.

```
var picker = app.picker.create({
inputEl: '#picker-input',
formatValue: function(values, displayValues) {
   return displayValues;
},
cols: [
    {
        values: ['hidden-variable-1','hidden-variable-2'],
        displayValues: ['Displayed Value 1','Displayed Value 2']
    }
]});
```